# Firebase Tutorial 1 Friendly chat Error occurred configuring root project 'android-start'

Tags: android, git, firebase

I am trying to start the Friendly Chat Firebase tutorial. But the gradle build throws an error and I can't really give anymore information as I don't know where to begin. However, a picture is worth a thousand words, and I believe that it contains everything relevant.

- Files downloaded from git google.json copied across
- Dependencies added and applied
- Build tools and IDE updated

I noticed there is only a project `build.gradle` I cant find a module `build.gradle`. I have no idea if this has anything to do with the issue though.

Originally threw error about unregistered VCS root, I clicked add root, but it didn't help.

[image]

Both `build.gradle` files are blue and when I click either one, it opens the tab named *android-start*(also blue), but the path is `C:\Users\User1\friendlychat\android-start\build.gradle` and the file contents are:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

EDIT: LogCat says `configure Android SDK`

If I click configure and set the SDK version and build tools version I get:

```
Error:(31, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments     [build_coejwo2h3fxgj0snev4rovui4$_run_closure4@512b9d86] on root project 'android-start' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
<a href="openFile:C:\Users\User1\friendlychat\android-start\build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

Comment: "cant find a module build.gradle"... Your picture clearly shows `app/build.gradle` and `/build.gradle` or your project. Please show them here as text with an [edit]

Comment: Thanks, edited. where does it say that it cant find build.gradle/

Comment: And the other one, please? Can you also click "show log in explorer" and see what is in there?

Comment: There is only the one gradle file it opens the same thing,
in logcat it says configure SDK

Comment: If it says to configure the SDK, then that means you need to open the SDK Manager and configure it

Comment: its been working fine in past projects, I think the problem maybe because I downloaded from github rather than created the project, Im not sure how to manually setup the SDK, I clicked configure before and set the build tookls version and sdk version
but then I get a different error see edit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the error is in project.gradle... I explain about it, this dependencie is correct because is inside the *project.gradle*:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

The other dependencie that needs firebase, needs is inside *app.gradle*:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And the *app.gradle* needs too this dependence:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
```

The finally gradles are these, *project.gradle*:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And the *app.gradle*:

```
...

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
}

//At final of the document
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Tell me if I can helps you, greetings!

Comment: Please can you explain where these gradle files are, 
Normally I see them at the bottom under "Gradle Scripts"
but in this file I have only the one,
there is a second build.gradle in my project source files, but they both open the same file as shown in the picture and OP

I downloaded this from Firebase Codelabs , I kind of expexted it to work out of the box as I havent even started the tutorial yet

Comment: @NathanWaddington Both files are actually called `build.gradle`, and there are two of them. They can clearly be seen in the image you have in your post

Comment: Exactly @NathanWaddington, the first one is *app.gradle* as *build.gradle* from app folder and the other one is *project.gradle* as *build.gradle* from project folder. Tell us about this changes, greetings!

Comment: This is where I am struggling, no matter which one I click on, it opens the same file in an android-start tab (as shown in picture)

Comment: Ok, with your view in the gradle scripts has 2 gradles as *build.gradle* this names has a extensions name *(Project: YourProject)* at first and  *(Module: app)* open both and see their structure, then follow my up indications.

Comment: Brilliant I did what you said, I had to open the project navigation 'app' drawer, the other gradle file was in there, once I had updated what you had said, the gradle file jumped back down under the Gradle Scripts section,
I have no idea why or how tho ,
and why did it not work from the start, is that a problem from firebase?

Comment: Just realised I had had it in project view and not android view, which is why I couldnt find the gradle file, 
I still don't understand why it didnt work from the start

Comment: @MerlíEscarpenterPérez Why at the end of the document. That does not make sense, there have to be a reason.

Comment: @AlexSanchez because the documentation say it: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup