# Firebase server SDK setup issuse

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am setting up an Android server project for pushing notification using [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup) from Firebase website. At first, I have set up the project at Firebase console and added the JSON file & Google services plugin.

But while syncing the project after adding 
`compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-server-sdk:3.0.1'`, there is the error:

```
Version: 3.0.1 is lower than the minimum version (9.0.0) required for google-services plugin.
```

My app build.gradle is-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ton.com.serverandroid"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-server-sdk:3.0.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My project build.gradle is

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have tried to use google-services version 2.1.0 but it wasn't working either with the error:

```
Conflict with dependency 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305'. Resolved versions for app (1.3.9) and test app (2.0.1) differ.
```

But I can't go farther in that case.

Comment: Sending downstream messages requires using an app server. You should **not** include the Server SDK in your Android app. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435750/how-to-send-device-to-device-messages-using-firebase-cloud-messaging

Answer (score 0):

I answer a similar question today, you can see the correct dependences here [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39879418/3996257), this ones are most important to import other dependencies in android client. Then for server sdk you need to add this one in *app.gradle*:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-server-sdk:[3.0.0,)'
```

For use FirebaseCloudMessaging you need other one in *app.gradle*:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0'
```

Tell us if you wan compile now, greetings!